# Проблема с l2tp туннелем

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, l2tp, xl2tp

Есть локальная сеть 1(выходит в интернет через beeline модем 4g, в режиме hotlink) 
Состоит из роутера zyxel(keenetik 4g ii) и видеорегистратора. 
Есть Пк(win 7) с которого нужно к этой локалке подключаться.

На vps(ubuntu 14.04) стоит l2tp сервис. 
Создал пользователя. 
Этим пользователем залогинился роутером, затем подключился через Пк. 
При подключении к vpn, могу серфить интернет, но не могу подключиться к видеорегистратору, хотя ему выдается ip 10.10.1.111 и на роутере созданы nat правила переадрессации на нужные порты. 
Не работает в том числе ping на 10.10.1.111

Товарищи экстрасенсы, в чем может быть проблема? 
Готов предоставить недостающие данные для полноты картины, главное сообщите что вам нужно знать.

Comment: судя из моего понимания написанного, в первую очередь подозрение падает именно на роутер и его настройки.

Comment: 1. у роутера в этой локальной сети, вероятно, адрес `10.10.1.1`. это адрес «пингуется» с вашего `пк`? 2. если у роутера есть `shell` или хотя бы веб-интерфейс для отправки `icmp`-пакетов, проверьте, «пингуется» ли видеорегистратор с самого роутера.

Answer (score 1):

У этой модели зюхеля замечен баг: Не отключается нат на тунеле через галку в веб морде. Маршруты на впс прописанны все?